# SQL Server 2017 Replication to 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is **snapshot replication** supported from SQL Server 2017 to SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft Documentations:

Backward compatibility is important to understand if you are upgrading, or if you have more than one version of SQL Server in a replication topology.

This link may help you.[Replication Backward Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-2017)